# C# Date validation

Tags: c#, date, validation, datetime, datetime-format

Hey guys I'm trying to validate the date format to be in dd/mm/yyyy and the end date to be later than the start date. start date validation was done earlier. Following code does not seem to be working. any leads on what's wrong with it?

```
    void EndingDate()

{
 if (Regex.IsMatch((Request.Form["EndDate"]), @"^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$"))
             {
                 DateTime StartingDate =Convert.ToDateTime((Request.Form["CommenceDate"]).Trim());
                 DateTime FinishDate = Convert.ToDateTime((Request.Form["EndDate"]).Trim());

                 if (StartingDate < FinishDate) 

                 {
                     Response.Write("The Commence date should be prior to End date");
                 }
             }
             else
                 Response.Write("End Date should be in dd/mm/yyyy");
}
EndingDate();
```

Comment: Regex is too much for just parsing a date (I don't even know if it is really possible). You can study how DateTime.TryParse works instead

Answer (score 2):

Using *regular expression* for `Date` *validation* can be *too complex*: different months has different days (`Sep` has `30` days, when `Oct` - `31`), let alone *leap years*.
Why not put `TryParse` or `TryParseExact`?

```
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["EndDate"], 
                             "d/M/yyyy", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                             DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                             out var FinishDate) && 
      DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["CommenceDate"], 
                             "d/M/yyyy", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                             DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                             out var StartingDate) &&
      StartingDate < FinishDate) {
    // Valid 
  }
  else {
    // Invalid
  }
```

In case you want *detailed* validation:

```
  if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["EndDate"], 
                              "d/M/yyyy", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                              DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                              out var FinishDate)) {
    Response.Write("End Date should be in dd/mm/yyyy"); 
  }
  else if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["CommenceDate"], 
                                   "d/M/yyyy", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                                   out var StartingDate)) {
    Response.Write("Commence Date should be in dd/mm/yyyy");
  }
  else if (StartingDate >= FinishDate) {
    Response.Write("The Commence date should be prior to End date");
  }
  else {
    // Valid  
  }
```